# How to sort the grid data based on drop down selection in angular js

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-grid

I have grid display in html and above the grid I have drop down list.
I have to sort the data of the grid view dynamically based on drop down list selected item. In grid one of filed is invisible.

Here is my working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1iJ7HVcv4CyMzNKUXHTi?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <br><br>
    <span  class=""><br/>
                    <select ng-model="name" ng-options="name.name for name in names">
                      <option value="">---- SELECT ----</option>
                    </select>
                 </span><br/>
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.names = [
                               {name:' NAME A – Z ', shade:'dark'},
                               {name:' NAME Z – A ', shade:'light'},
                               {name:' ID LOW TO HIGH', shade:'dark'},
                               {name:' ID HIGH TO LOW', shade:'dark'}


                            ];





    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50,id:1},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43,id:2},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27,id:3},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29,id:4},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34,id:5}];




    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' ,
                   columnDefs: [
            {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
            {field:'age', displayName:'Age'},
            {field:'id', displayName:'Id', visible:false}
        ] 
    };
});
```

Comment: I would suggest clicking on the grid header to do all those sorting functions. It is there by default.... Click on 'Name' to sort it either in Ascending or Descending Order.

Comment: @AlaguMS it is mandatory for drop down ,that to the id is not displayed in grid but it has in drop down by selecting the drop down i have to sort the grid .

Comment: with out answer the question need not to down vote the question .

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/XYmwkr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Add an ng-change to your select:

```
<select ng-change="sort()" ng-model="name" ng-options="name.name for name in names">
```

Add some information to your model about what your select options mean:

```
 $scope.names = [
                           {name:' NAME A – Z ', shade:'dark', col: 'name', dir: 'asc'},
                           {name:' NAME Z – A ', shade:'light', col: 'name', dir: 'desc'},
                           {name:' ID LOW TO HIGH', shade:'dark', col: 'id', dir: 'asc'},
                           {name:' ID HIGH TO LOW', shade:'dark', col: 'id', dir: 'desc'}


                        ];
```

And tell ng-grid what it is supposed to do:

```
    $scope.sort = function(){
  $scope.gridOptions.sortInfo = {fields:[$scope.name.col],directions:[$scope.name.dir]};
  $scope.gridOptions.sortBy($scope.name.col);

}
```

Updated plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yP4nK6wgmD3picuz3ZIf?p=preview

Comment: @Imyers thank you ,you got my requirement and guided proper answer ,but where as some one not got the hidden id concept and down voted the question .

Comment: @Imyers could you please answer the question:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604384/how-can-i-get-server-side-pagination-in-ng-grid-in-angularsjs]